# Serenity screenplay pattern- upload file

Tags: java, serenity-bdd

We are trying cucumber serenity framework for end to end tests. I am fairly new the technology and I tired this simple code below.

```
actor.attemptsTo(Enter.theValue(path).into(Upload));
```

where path is the location of file i am trying to upload using browser's upload widget.Has anyone ever managed to perform actions like this using serenity screen play pattern.

Its really making us think of giving up serenity and just use cucumber-selenium framework as I can easily perform this using Upload.sendkeys(path);
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

**AS requested: Listing Steps:**

```
public class ListingSteps
{
  @Before
  public void set_the_stage() {
    OnStage.setTheStage(new OnlineCast());
  }

  @Given("^(.*) is able to click import products$") public void userIsAbleToClick(String actorName) throws Throwable
  {
    theActorCalled(actorName).wasAbleTo(Start.theApplication());

  }
  @When("^s?he imports a  single item successfully$") public void heImportsASingleItemSuccessfully() throws Throwable
  {
    theActorInTheSpotlight().attemptsTo(Import.spreadsheet());
  }
  @Then("^(.*) are listed on ebay and amazon with all the right information$") public void itemsAreListedOnEbayAndAmazonWithAllTheRightInformation(String actorName, String SKU)
     throws Throwable
```

{
//pending

```
  }
```

Ignore then for now as its work in progress.

**Import class:**

```
public class Import implements Task
{
  protected String path =
      "C:\\somePathToFile\\populated_excel.xlsx";
  public static Import spreadsheet()
  {
    return instrumented(Import.class);
  }
  @Override public <T extends Actor> void performAs(T actorName)
  {
    actorName.attemptsTo(Click.on(Products.ProductsScreen));
    actorName.attemptsTo(Click.on(Products.Upload));
    actorName.attemptsTo(Enter.theValue(path).into(Browse).thenHit(Keys.RETURN));//this is the line which is giving errors
    actorName.attemptsTo(Click.on(Products.UploadButton));
  }
}
```

**Target Browse**

```
public class Products
{
 public static Target Browse = Target.the("browse file").locatedBy("//input[@type='file']");
}
```

Comment: Could you post the full test, including how you have defined the Upload field?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing these lines?
actorName.attemptsTo(Click.on(Products.ProductsScreen));
actorName.attemptsTo(Click.on(Products.Upload));

You don't need to open the upload file component, only write the file path directly to the input file element and perform the submit.

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to get this working was by using the FileToUpload class:

```
import net.thucydides.core.pages.components.FileToUpload;

FileToUpload fileToUpload = new FileToUpload(driver, fileName);    
fileToUpload.fromLocalMachine().to(webElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with a simple:

```
import java.nio.file.*;

Path data = null;
try {
    data = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(file).toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException ignore) {}
ACTOR.attemptsTo(Upload.theFile(data).to(target));
```

`file` is an actual file that exists on your classpath, in `src/test/resources` if you have a Maven project.

`target` is something like:

```
Target.the("Image upload").located(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
```